# Can i change HTML structure with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I need to change 2 divs up and down by using javascript dom manipulation, without touching html.

```html
<div class="div1"> this needs to go bottom</div>
<div class="div2"> and this needs to go up</div>
```

Is it possible to manipulate html structure with js?

Comment: Yes, you do it by doing exactly what you described, [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) manipulation.  Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mre] showing your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks, i'll be more cautious about searching before posting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this, swap the elements order in the parent node.

```
var div1 = document.getElementsByClassName("div1")[0];

var div2 = document.getElementsByClassName("div2")[0];

div2.parentNode.insertBefore(div2, div1);
```